# Trouble inserting React object into sequelize/MySQL database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

My front end and backend are connected but it is not inputting the values into my MySQL database from a React form.  When I console log the response I get from my React app it logs

```
{name: "han solo", email: "han@virginia.edu", message: "fsbfbsf"}
```

but my database logs the results as

```
{id: 4, updatedAt: "2020-05-28T03:11:31.983Z", createdAt: "2020-05-28T03:11:31.983Z"}
```

My database model is:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Messages = sequelize.define("Messages", {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    message: DataTypes.STRING
  });
  return Messages;
};
```

My post route is:

```
 // POST route for saving a new Message
  app.post("/api/messages", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.Messages.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      message: req.body.message
    }).then(function(dbMessages) {
      // We have access to the new Message as an argument inside of the callback function
      res.json(dbMessages);
    });
  });
```

My handleFormSubmit function on my front end is:

```
handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (
      this.state.name === "" ||
      this.state.email === "" ||
      this.state.message === ""
    ) {
      this.setState({
        formError: true
      });
      return false;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        formError: false
      });
      const obj = {
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        message: this.state.message
      };
      console.log(obj);
      axios
        .post(url, {obj})
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));

      this.setState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        message: ""
      });
    }
  };
```

It seems like the default values are inserting but not the input values from the React Form, but the form values console log as an object

Comment: have you get any error in inserting data into db ?

Comment: No the database loads default values.

Comment: Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Messages` (`id`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'2020-05-28 22:56:35','2020-05-28 22:56:35');
[nodemon] restarting du

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to bind the values to state, and I was declaring obj as {obj} instead of obj. Corrections are below

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getName = this.getName.bind(this);
    this.getEmail = this.getEmail.bind(this);
    this.getMessage = this.getMessage.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);




 axios 
    .post(url, obj)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
```